# How to stub a method with out parameter using custom delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, rhino-mocks, stubbing

I am trying to stub a method that has an `out` paramteter using RhinoMock's `Do` method, but I keep getting the message *cannot resolve symbol outParam*. Here's the stubbing part:

```
private static void FakeClientsLoading(MyClass fakeClass, IEnumerable<string> clientsToLoad)
{
    fakeClass.Stub(
        x =>
            x.LoadClientsFromDb(Arg<string>.Is.Anything,
                out Arg<object>.Out(null).Dummy))
        .Do(
            new LoadClientsFromDbAction(
                (someString, out outParam ) =>
                    TestHelper.LoadClients(someString, clientsToLoad)));
 }
```

And here is my custom delegate declaration:

```
public delegate void LoadClientsFromDbAction(string s, out object outParam);
```

What I'd like to achieve is to run the test helper method whenever `LoadClientsFromDb` is invoked. From my understanding `outParam` should be mapped to whatever is passed as the `out` parameter to the called method, but it doesn't seem to work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I have finally found the answer to my question. It turns out that, quoting section 26.3.1 from [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx):

> Specifically, a delegate type D is compatible with an anonymous method
>   or lambda-expression L provided:
>
> > If L is a lambda expression that has an implicitly typed parameter list, D has no ref or out parameters.

This means that you need an explicitly typed parameter list in order to create a lambda with an `out` parameter.

That's not all, though. It is still necessary to assign a value to the `out` parameter upon exiting the anonymous method.

The final and working code:

```
private static void FakeClientsLoading(MyClass fakeClass, IEnumerable<string> clientsToLoad)
{
    fakeClass.Stub(
        x =>
            x.LoadClientsFromDb(Arg<string>.Is.Anything,
                out Arg<object>.Out(null).Dummy))
        .Do(
            new LoadClientsFromDbAction(
                (string someString, out object outParam) =>
                {
                    outParam = null;
                    TestHelper.LoadClients(someString, clientsToLoad);
                }
                ));
}
```